# Putting a Curl Response into a usable php format

Tags: php, curl

I'm wondering if anybody can help me put the below curl response into PHP variables.

[image]

If possible, i'd like to extract each of the goods_id and goods_descriptions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The response is in JSON format.  You should try the json_decode() method and if you have specific issues edit your post to show example.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `json_decode()`

```
$data = json_decode ($result);
echo $data->result->goods[0]->goods_id;
```

Or, if you prefer associative arrays:

```
$data = json_decode ($result, true);
echo $data['result']['goods'][0]['goods_id'];
```

[PHP.net documentation on json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)